# Failure in "file module Update #8700"

Tags: 8, updating

```
file module

Update #8700
•Failed: Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: Field storage definition for 'type' could not be found. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorageSchema->getEntitySchema() (line 979 of /var/www/xxxxxxx.com/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php).
```

This message is shown after running update.php

I believe this is also related to a brand new problem we're having since the upgrade to 8.9.7 -- we can no longer add images.

Need advice for how to perform this update. At this point I just want it done, so even if I have to manually hack something I'm fine with that. I can revisit how to fix things properly once the site is working again.

Comment: This was asked before. Can't find it, might be closed and deleted. The core file entity doesn't have a field `type`, only the deprecated module File Entity. See this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity/issues/3060204

Answer (score 0):

This is probably connected to the module [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity).

You find a patch in this issue:

https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity/issues/3060204

Comment: I might just be tired today... I don't have file_entity installed!